# cant publish my boostrap page on github page

Tags: html, css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3, github-pages

I published my website on Github page. for the second time. But error appears which I don't understand. I used bootstrap for my page, here is the error

> "Your site is having problems building: A file was included in
>   bootstrap-3.3.7/docs/components.html that is a symlink or does not
>   exist in your _includes directory. For more information, see
>   https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-file-is-a-symlink/."

here is my github repository https://github.com/makopa/portfolio

Comment: can you atleast share your repo or some sort of code for us to look what you have done

Comment: Did you follow the link and read about symlinks in order to make sure you aren't placing them in your gh page branch?

Comment: here is my repository link https://github.com/makopa/portfolio

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue while deploying on GitHub an old website built in 2017 with Bulma. After updating all my dependencies, I still got the same error as Makopa. I deleted the /docs folder, redeployed with git status, add, commit and push and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

That [`bootstrap-3.3.7/docs/components.html`](https://github.com/makopa/portfolio/blob/master/bootstrap-3.3.7/docs/components.html) does indeed have include directives:

```
{% include components/glyphicons.html %}
{% include components/dropdowns.html %}
{% include components/button-groups.html %}
```

And the help page [does mention](https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-file-is-a-symlink/):

> Search for the include tag to see where you've referenced other files. For example: `{% include cool_header.html %}`.
>   Copy or move any symlinked files into the `_includes` directory of your GitHub Pages repository.

Maybe you could simply *not* include the `doc` folder of the bootstrap framework (so delete it) in your repo.

Comment: thanks for the help @vonc in what folder i can check and input all of that?

Comment: @Makopa you can clone your repo, delete the folder `docs`, add, commit and push back and see if the publication goes well. When you clone your repo in `/a/path`, the folder to check will be `/a/path/portfolio/bootstrap-3.3.7`: if you see `docs` in there, remove it. Add, commit and push.